# Handlebars does not find dynamic partial

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have this partial:

_info.hbs

```
info
```

And I have this helper function in my helpers file:

helper.js

```
module.exports = {
  infoPartial: function(context, options) {
    return '/absolute/path/to/_info.hbs';    
  }
};
```

My template is this:

```
{{> ('infoPartial') }}
```

And when I call my template I get

```
"The partial /absolute/path/to/_info could not be found"
```

I don't know, why handlebars can't find the partial. Maybe someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: I think you should include tags about what server-side Handlebars view engine and framework you are using.

Comment: @76484 Ain't usin' no view engine. Just plain vanilla handlebars. Would have tagged of course if otherwise.

Comment: If not using a view engine, how are you registering your partials?

Comment: @76484 I don't. I want to use dynamic loading. If I understood the handlebars documentation properly, _dynamic loading_ registers partials _on the fly_ the first time they are called. Registering the partials upfront would be static.

Comment: I don't think Handlebars is going to be able to dynamically load node modules. As far as I know, the _dynamic_ part of Handlebars' "dynamic partials" just refers to the ability to use a variable to control which partial is rendered at execution time; but all partials must still be registered. What documentation are you referring to?

Comment: @76484 I was referring to https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#dynamic-partials . My bad, I mislead myself. By the time I was reading that part, I was hoping to find a solution to find a solution for on demand partial loading (i.e. including registration). But thanks and due to your comments, I was pointed in towards the right direction. So, there's no way around partial registration upfront. You've really helped me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you cannot pass an absolute path to a partial to the partial resolver. The path resolution is done by the framework. Instead of the path, you should just be passing the *name* of the partial. In your case, this would mean replacing `'/absolute/path/to/_info.hbs'` with simply `'_info'`.

Comment: That was my understanding too. Seriously, I've checked the docs. But calling '_info' didn't work either. That's why I resorted to using the absolute path.